# UIWebView Not Showing Up

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview

I just added a new UIWebView and it doesn't seem to be showing up. I'm pretty new here, so this could be a very simple error.

I created the view using the storyboard and dragged it into my GuideViewController.h

This is my GuideViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface GuideViewController : UIViewController
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIWebView *newsWebView;

@end
```

This is my GuideViewController.m

```
#import "GuideViewController.h"

@interface GuideViewController ()

@end

@implementation GuideViewController


@synthesize newsWebView;

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSURL *newsURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.yahoo.com"];
    NSURLRequest *newsRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:newsURL];
    [newsWebView loadRequest:newsRequest];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

This is what I'm using to add the view to my app delegate. I already have a sidebar menu added.

```
@implementation AppDelegate

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{

    VidViewController *vidViewController = [[VidViewController alloc] init];

    GuideViewController *newsWebView = [[GuideViewController alloc] init];
    UINavigationController *navController1 = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:vidViewController];

[self.window setRootViewController:navController1];

    SelectVideo1 *selectVideo1 = [[SelectVideo1 alloc] initWith:@"Test"];
    //[self.navController pushViewController:selectVideo1 animated:YES];

    SelectVideo1 *selectVideo2 = [[SelectVideo1 alloc] initWith:@"Latest News"];

    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    UIStoryboard *tabStoryBoard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"TabStoryboard" bundle:nil];
    UIStoryboard *navStoryBoard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"NavStoryboard" bundle:nil];
    UINavigationController *navController = [navStoryBoard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Nav Controller"];
    UITabBarController *tabController = [tabStoryBoard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Tab Controller"];


    ViewController *redVC, *greenVC;
    redVC = [[ViewController alloc] init];
    greenVC = [[ViewController alloc] init];



    RootController *menuController = [[RootController alloc]
                                      initWithViewControllers:@[navController, selectVideo1, selectVideo2, tabController, newsWebView]
                                      andMenuTitles:@[@"Test", @"Videos", @"Latest News", @"Walkthroughs", @"Official News"]];
    self.window.rootViewController = menuController;
    self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}



@end
```

The view shows up in the menu bar, but when I click it, nothing happens. I believe the problem lies in my appdelegate and how I call the view?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a nib file to define your GuideViewController, use

```
GuideViewController *newsWebView = [[GuideViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"Insert_Nib_Name_Here" bundle:nil];
```

If you define your GuideViewController in a storyboard, use

```
UIStoryboard *navStoryBoard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"NavStoryboard" bundle:nil];
GuideViewController *newsWebView = [navStoryBoard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Insert_Guide_Controller_Name_Here"];
```

If that doesn't work, make sure your IBOutlet UIWebView is connected (control+drag from the UIWebView object in your nib file)

You can also just add the UIWebView programmatically.

In GuideViewController.h, you probably want to conform to the UIWebViewDelegate protocol. Implement the methods to control the UIWebView's functionality

```
@interface GuideViewController : UIViewController <UIWebViewDelegate>
```

In GuideViewController.m...

```
- (GuideViewController*)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        //Adjust the frame accordingly if you don't want it to take up the whole view
        self.newsWebView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame];
        self.newsWebView.delegate = self;
        [self.view addSubview:self.newsWebView];
    }
    return self;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I tried the programatically and get this error when adding guideviewcontroller: assigning to 'id<UIWebViewDelegate>' from incompatible type 'GuideViewController *_strong'

Comment: and when i try to do it with the storyboard, I get this error: http://i.imgur.com/mgN1TOz.png

Comment: Lastly, I tried adding your code since I'm using the storyboard, but I receive this error: http://i.imgur.com/GKV5oyM.png

Comment: Your first error is most likely because you didn't conform to the <UIWebViewDelegate> protocol. The second error can be solved by adding __weak before IBOutlet to your ivar. As for the last error, you need to call instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier on your UIStoryboard instance navStoryBoard, not the class itself. See my edited answer.